# Place clickable event over already existing event in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to build a scheduling type system off of the free Full Calendar. The main catch is that the user defines which times his/her service is available.

Currently on my calendar I have events for times in which the user has specified availability, and times that have been booked by other users, I'm trying to leverage the drag and drop features that are on Full Calendar. Currently a user can select the calendar and drag his/her event, and if that crosses over a booked time or a time specified not available the event goes away, and if he drags over just the time specified available the event stays.

The main problem I have is that I need these events to stack on top of each other, and for a user to be able to click on the time available event and for the clicked event to appear over-top, currently I have to click just to the right or left of the available event. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ5Ih.jpg This is what the calendar looks like currently)

Currently I am trying to do this by using the eventClick function and the selectFn which looks like

```
 function eventClick(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
// call selectFn
}

function selectFn(start, end, ev) {
// do stuff to check if select is place-able or not
}
```

I've tried passing in start, end, ev into the eventClick function but it does not work, any help or ideas would be appreciated, sorry for the long post.

Comment: What I could do is just make the "Available" events display none and maybe that might do the trick

Comment: no-one can really help you unless you post the code that isn't working. Just giving a vague outline and saying "it doesn't work" is pretty much useless. We can't read your mind.

Comment: There was just a bunch of code I tried to summarise everything as best I could. I eventually figured it out but thanks for the advice! Next time I'll be sure to post everything

Comment: Also it was less of a "my code isn't working", more of a "any ideas of how to go about this problem"

Comment: I'd have been happy to comment on the general approach, but all you gave was the function definitions of the callbacks that are already documented by FullCalendar, but no description of what you were trying (or intending to try) to do within them. You do also mention something you tried which "does not work", so I assumed you actually had something worth showing. Anyway glad you figured the problem out, good luck with the rest of it.